# java.net.ServerSocket.accept () doesn't return on Android

Tags: android, sockets, telnet

I am trying to make a way to telnet to an unrooted Droid. I have the `INTERNET` permission active, I have my device connected on the same network as my `Mac OS X` box via WiFi, and I am able to ping the port I opened.

In initial experiments, I got it to work on a rooted test device, but I had the socket handlers run on the `UI Thread` rather than a separate thread. Now that I have the network modules on a separate thread, I can't get `ServerSocket.accept ()` to return. It works on Google's version of android (vanilla), but not on Samsung's or Sony-Ericsson's.

When I telnet to it, my attempt would time out, and `logcat` wouldn't print out any exceptions or errors.

Here is a link to a google-code repo of my code: [Google-code Repository](https://code.google.com/p/android-socket-experiment/)

I am running `ServerScoket.accept ()` on a separate thread, and run the stream processors on another thread as well. Comments on my design (i.e. I should use `Handler`s or `AsyncTasks`) are extremely welcome. Right now, in order to Toast the messages received via telnet, I use a Handler with the looper being acquired via a `Context`.

The following is what I get when I run `netstat -n` on the adb shell on the non-working devices:

```
~$ adb shell netstat -n
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7203         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47609        127.0.0.1:7777         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         127.0.0.1:47609        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47610        127.0.0.1:7777         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         127.0.0.1:47610        ESTABLISHED
```

The difference is that in the working devices, they list an IP with my port open in the state, LISTEN.

**UPDATE**: Having the `<uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>` set in my `android_manifest`, I tried changing the port number to `689`. It didn't work; I got a `BindException`, saying that I may be lacking the INTERNET permission. So, I changed it to `1989`, and I went back to everything working until `accept ()`. I assume this is because I ran it on a non-root phone, and I don't have access to ports `1024` and below.

**UPDATE**: I ran a really similar program on my Mac, and it worked fine when I tried telnetting to my Mac using the IP address assigned to me. It didn't work when I tried telnetting from another Mac but it didn't seem to connect; the connection would timeout. It did work over an ad-hoc network, though. I still have yet to try it using the droid, but I will update this asap.

**UPDATE**: I managed to get the app working on 3 separate Droids running Vanilla (Android released by google). It worked on a Nexus, an Apanda A60 (my first device; adb has ceased to detect it for some reason.), and a custom-made, unbranded tablet. Still, because I already offered a pretty big bounty, I plan on seeing this through to the end.

As stated earlier, my app works with Vanilla versions of android, but not with modified versions. The three phones that failed to run it were all mid-range models; 2 `Samsung GT-i5503`s, and a `Sony-Ericcson E16i`.

Comment: Remember that you cannot "ping" a port, only an IP address. So your successful ping only tells you that the device is connected to the network. Can you post your code that initiates the server socket?

Comment: No you didn't, because ping does not take a port.

Comment: alright, I ran `ping 192.168.1.3:8989`. If I ran `ping 192.168.1.3`, nothing would happen. Only if I appended `:8989` would it work. I don't really know how to express what I did.

Comment: With whose implementation of ping?

Comment: I'm using the default `ping` available on the terminal of the macbook I'm using.

Comment: I'm gonna read `man ping` now. Apparently `ping 192.168.1.3` gets a Request_timeout, while `ping 192.168.1.3:.*` works (.* represents a regular expression).

Comment: @anonymous Android runs on *nix, 'ping' is sending a UDP Echo - which requires a port. If it was running on Windows (e.g. Windows XP development machine) it would send an ICMP 'ping' (which does not require a port).

Comment: @anonymous care to share any of the code around the call to `accept()` and what you changed that it stopped working?

Comment: @CrackerJack9: thanks for that info about ping. As for the code, I posted everything in the Google-Code repository. The code that contains the network related programmin stuff can be found here: `https://code.google.com/p/android-socket-experiment/source/browse/src/org/syx/droid/telnet/test/TelnetServer.java`

Comment: @anonymous You are listening to TCP port, so you should use `telnet 192.168.1.3 1089` (or whatever other port your app listens to instead of *1089*) instead of `ping` (since it uses UDPs).

Comment: @anonymous I just ran it on an emulator and it is listening on port 1089 as expected....

Comment: @anonymous I got your code today and did a run on HTC Phone with HTC Sense (which I think is classified as non-Vanilla Android) installed. I was able to telnet from my MacOSX to the phone. Just an FYI that it works with some of non-Vanilla phone as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a networking issue, rather than a code issue. I used your latest project and it is listening on the port, as expected.

I added this to `TelnetServer.setupServerSocket()` to confirm some information:

```
Log.i("TelnetServer", "ServerSocket Address: " + this.server.getLocalSocketAddress());
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                Log.i("TelnetServer", "Listen On: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress());
            }
        }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    Log.e("TelnetServer", ex.toString(), ex);
}
```

This will print all of the addresses your service is listening on (if it is listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:xxx (printed after ServerSocket Address:)).

You should run `emulator` with the `-tcpdump <file>` option and also provide this. It will confirm any connection is being attempted. My hunch is that your client is not able to access the server, which is why the server is not receiving the connection - rather than an issue with the code.

Please provide the tcpdump file, your IP Address (of the client) and the logcat output (including the ServerSocket Address and Listen On statements) for further analysis.

Comment: to be honest, I haven't had time to confirm that it is a network error, but as of now, it is my best hypothesis. On a side note, you did tell me how `ping` works, so there's that too.

Answer (score 1):

See if netstat -n from the adb shell shows anything actually listening on the port you chose at the time when accept() is not returning.

Also realize that when not running as root, you can only bind unprivileged ports, of which the default telnet port is not an example.  Does your code check that bind() was successful?

UPDATE:

Since the code works on a number of devices (where netstat -n would presumably list the socket) the failure to list it on the subject device should probably remain a focus.  The Java ServerSocket methods depend on a socket factory which can be over-ridden to let you do distinct calls to socket(), bind(), and listen() specifying fuller details, so it may make sense to try your code that way.  There's another case floating around where a device's attempt to support ipv6 seems to be causing someone similar problems, and at least on other java platforms creating the socket at a lower level to specify ipv4 seems like a promising answer.

Comment: I posted my code, but I didn't call `bind ()`. I set the port to `8989`, and it didn't throw any errors. How would I go about running netstat -n from the adb shell? Do I run ADB the run `netstat -n`?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out the `adb shell` now, so I ran it and discovered that my port wasn't on the list.

Comment: ServerSocket() should be calling bind() for you, but if it's not on the netstat list it didn't happen and you won't be able to accept connections.  Do you have internet permission?

Comment: Yes. I added it to under the Permissions tab under `uses-permission`. I also didn't get any errors or exceptions about the INTERNET permission being needed (I remember getting this in an earlier attempt)

Comment: I changed the return statement of `setupServerSocket ()`; instead of `return true`, I had it return `this.socket.isBound ()`, which returned true, but still wouldn't work or show up on `netstat -n`.

Comment: are you certain the packet is even getting to the machine, when you say `accept()` is not returning? why do you assume it should return?

Comment: How about logging and ServerSocket.getInetAddress() and ServerSocket.getLocalPort() and see if they are expected.  You will not be able to bind a port below about 1024 as a non-root user.

Comment: @CrackerJack9: As of now, I have very few assumptions left. I know that `accept ()` is supposed to return a `java.net.Socket` when I telnet to it because that is what the documentation says it's supposed to do. I tried running a really similar test on my box, and it worked fine. I just ran another experiment, but this time using multiple threads (very similar architecture to the I use now for android). It worked when I telnetted to my own machine, but not from another machine. I didn't use `localhost`, rather, I used the IP assigned to me.

Comment: @Chris: my `InetAddress () ` is set to 0.0.0.0, but I tried setting it to the IP assigned to my Droid, but I got the same results. My ports are usually set to either `1989` or `8989`, but I tried setting it to `689` once. I got an exception, implying that it really will throw an exception if I use a port under `1024`, further implying that it isn't an issue. Still, I could be wrong.

Comment: @anonymous - is that the port you are putting in, or what ServerSocket.getLocalPort() returns that it has used?  I don't think this is going to work until your socket shows up in netstat.  Can you find some demo networking app to try?  And randomly, what is your jdk version?

Comment: I'm running JDK 6, `getLocalPort ()` returns `8989`, which is the port my app is listening to. Are you talking about an Android network app, or a Java network app for my Mac?

Comment: Somebody else's android app using those java classes - an open source one with a prebuilt apk you can try, then rebuild from source would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have tried most of the things are you are just few steps from getting it right on two particular devices.

Just a thought, If not point to point, why not Use Muti-casting for service registration and discovery in local area networks.

This is the java implementation [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/)

and this is its [Android demo](https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo/tree/master/AndroidDnssdDiscoveryEclipse)

EDIT : Rather I should say to check connectivity with that two devices.