# Server Socket not listening on correct ip address

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I've written a Server Socket Activity, and a client in C#. But my C# client never connect with the android server. **While searching I found this question. [java.net.ServerSocket.accept() doesn't return on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273323/java-net-serversocket-accept-doesnt-return-on-android)**

My Server Socket is listening on ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=5000]) instead of 10.0.2.15.Kindly guide me in right direction.

```
    private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                        && InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress())) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

 public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                if (SERVERIP != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                        }
                    });
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                    while (true) {
                        // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                                }
                            });
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Error");
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of the mobile device to work as a server depends on the firewall configuration of your mobile internet provider. Normally this is disabled. This type of connectivity may only work when the device is connected through wireless rather than mobile broadband.

[0.0.0.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is in any case an invalid address. Ignore it when trying to get your host address.

Comment: I want to test this app on my emulator! is there anyway to get this done?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not an 'invalid address'.

Comment: It is used to designate designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target and is non routable.

Answer (score 0):

> ServerSocket not listening on correct IP address

Yes it is. There's nothing wrong with the ServerSocket returning 0.0.0.0 as its local address. That's INADDR_ANY. It just means it will accept connections via any local interface. This is not your problem.

Comment: but when i tried to use IPAddress.Any in C# Client! it still not working

Comment: You were already using it. That's why you saw 0.0.0.0. It's the default. You didn't change anything by specifying it explicitly. This is not the problem.